# OpenGL Translation - Coordinate

Tags: opengl, glut, collision

I'm attempting to make a simple game that allows you to jump around the screen and onto the platforms without leaving the screen or falling through the platforms.

So far i have managed to create a little 2D square which i refer to as my sprite or character along with 2 platforms.

I have finally made my sprite move up, down, left and right (no jump yet) but my collision for leaving the screen isn't working how i thought it would...

What i'm doing is using `glTranslate(x,y,z)` to move my sprite depending on the `key` input from the keyboard and testing a collision between the sprite and the screen before. Unfortunately i think im getting confused with the coordinates being used for the translation inside my `collisionScreen`.

Something to note is, i can not take my sprite past the origin of where the sprite was initially drawn `ie "0"` no matter where or when the sprite is drawn.

Comment: Is `mySKeyboard()` definitely being called?

Comment: Yes it is because the sprite moves around the screen. It can go right or up forever, and left and down until it reaches 0 on X or Y at its origin :(

Comment: Your collision logic sets the position to zero (some strangely by subtracting it from itself) when your object reaches either edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that:

```
void collisionScreen (int x, int y)
{
    //stops sprite leaving current screen size
    if(x_pos < 0 || x_pos+s1_W > winX)
        x_pos -= x_pos;
    if(y_pos < 0 || y_pos+s1_H > winY)
        y_pos -= y_pos;
}
```

doesn't actually use the `x` and `y` parameters you pass into it.

Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
void collisionScreen (int x, int y)
{
    //stops sprite leaving current screen size
    if(x_pos < 0)
        x_pos = 0;
    else if(x_pos+s1_W > winX)
        x_pos = winX - s1_W;

    if(y_pos < 0)
        y_pos = 0;
    else if(y_pos+s1_H > winY)
        y_pos = winY - s1_H;
}
```

Also, your sprite will not pass `0` as that is what this method is designed to do.